# Finding lie algebra of a group by using exp map and tangent space

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm studying Lie groups and I am in trouble with finding lie algebras of the classical groups. How can I calculate $\mathfrak{sp}(n,\mathbb{C})$ or $\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{R})$ using exp map and tangent space of these groups?

Comment: There are several steps in the process---perhaps you can be more specific about what's giving you trouble?

Comment: Anyway, see Chapter 8 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*: https://books.google.at/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&lpg=PP1&dq=introduction%20to%20smooth%20manifolds&pg=PA197#v=onepage&q=lie%20algebra&f=false and in particular the example on p. 197.

Comment: I have checked that question and it there is not anything about exp map as a 1-PS in the answers.

Comment: The exponential map is in the answer there, see the comments to it. It is very similar to the answer below here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde,                                                                                                            Hi, I'm following Groups and Symmetries by Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach to learn matrix groups and some lie theory. I'm studying on my own so I need a self-contained reference. I prefer one that calculates lie algebras of some lie groups explicitly or gives an introduction about what a tangent space is. So, can you suggest me some  books/lecture notes, please?

Comment: Yes, take the  book "Lie groups, Lie algebras, and Cohomology" by Knapp. There you will find all necessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.

I'll do one for $SO(3)$ and I guess you can figure out the general way of proceeding.

OUTLINE: We will start from a general form for an element of $SO(3)$ then we'll consider all the curves passing from the identity and we will derive effectively the tangent space in the identity. We'll find a base and that will be the Lie Algebra. If you exponentiate the tangent vector at the tangent space at the identity you'll get newly the element of the Lie Group $SO(3)$

Let's suppose that you know that every rotation can be seen as a rotation of an angle $\theta$ around a vector $\mathbf{v}=x\mathbf{e_x}+y\mathbf{e_y}+z\mathbf{e_z}$.

Then every element of $SO(3)$ can be parametrized as
$$R_{\mathbf{v}}\left(\theta\right)=\mathbb{1}+\sin\theta X+\left(1-\cos\theta\right)X^{2},$$ where $X$ is this matrix
$$X=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -z & y\\
z & 0 & -x\\
-y & x & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
If you're smart you already understood that I'm cheating (because this parametrization of $SO(3)$ is already a sort of exponential... but let's continue...

So given the parametrization, a general rotation matrix is given by
$$R\left(\theta,\,x,\,y,\,z\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x^{2}+\cos\theta\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right) & \left(1-\cos\theta\right)xy-z\sin\theta & \left(1-\cos\theta\right)xz+y\sin\theta\\
\left(1-\cos\theta\right)xy+z\sin\theta & y^{2}+\cos\theta\left(x^{2}+z^{2}\right) & \left(1-\cos\theta\right)yz-x\sin\theta\\
\left(1-\cos\theta\right)xz-y\sin\theta & \left(1-\cos\theta\right)yz-x\sin\theta & z^{2}+\cos\theta\left(y^{2}+x^{2}\right)
\end{array}\right),$$

Now take a regular curve $\theta\left(t\right)$ such that $\theta\left(0\right)=0$ and let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with coordinates $\left(x,\,y,\,z\right)$. The tangent vector of the curve is then given by 
$$\frac{d}{dt}R_{\mathbf{v}}\left(\theta\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)\sin\theta & xy\sin\theta-z\cos\theta & xz\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\\
xy\sin\theta+z\cos\theta & -\left(x^{2}+z^{2}\right)\sin\theta & yz\sin\theta-x\cos\theta\\
xz\sin\theta-y\cos\theta & yz\sin\theta+x\cos\theta & -\left(y^{2}+x^{2}\right)\sin\theta
\end{array}\right)\cdot\dot{\theta}\left(t\right)$$.
Then in $t=0$
$$\frac{d}{dt}R_{\mathbf{v}}\left(\theta\right)|_{t=0}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -z & y\\
z & 0 & -x\\
-y & x & 0
\end{array}\right)\cdot\dot{\theta}\left(t\right).$$
So let's now consider the axis $\mathbf{x}=\left(1,\,0,\,0\right)$,
$\mathbf{y}=\left(0,\,1,\,0\right)$ and $\mathbf{z}=\left(0,\,0,\,1\right)$
Then you have
$$ E_{1}=\frac{d}{dt}R_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\theta\right)|_{t=0} =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\cdot\dot{\theta}\left(t\right),$$
$$E_{2}=\frac{d}{dt}R_{\mathbf{y}}\left(\theta\right)|_{t=0} =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\cdot\dot{\theta}\left(t\right),$$
$$E_{3}=\frac{d}{dt}R_{z}\left(\theta\right)|_{t=0} =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\cdot\dot{\theta}\left(t\right).$$
Then you have a base for the Lie Algebra of $SO(3)$ and a general vector $X$ in the tangent space of $SO(3)$ at the identity can be written as
$$X=xE_{1}+yE_{2}+zE_{3},$$
 If you exponentiate the general vector of the Lie Algebra you get the general rotation in the exponential form 
$$R_{\mathbf{v}}\left(\theta\right)=\exp\left[\theta X\right],$$ with
$$X=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -z & y\\
z & 0 & -x\\
-y & x & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
which in fact was the parametrization we were starting from. Hope gave you some hints on how to proceed. The other classic and more easy way to proceed it's just to do a taylor expansion, but I think this one it really explicit.

Comment: @Daco,                                                                                                                                               Hello, Hi, I'm trying to learn matrix groups and some lie theory by following Groups and Symmetries by Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach. I'm studying on my own so I need a self-contained reference. I need one that calculates lie algebras of some lie groups explicitly or gives an introduction about what a tangent space is before using them. So, can you suggest me some books/lecture notes, please? P.s: Thank you for the very enlightening answer.

Comment: What do you need it for? Physics, Mathematical Physics or just Mathematics? Because references may change drastically

Comment: I need it for just Mathematics. I also found some Physics/Mathematical Physics references very useful for me.

Comment: Did you already study Differential Geometry and/or Riemannian Geometry?

Comment: Supposing that you don't know nothing I would use this bibliography to start with:

*** Gilmore, "Lie Groups, Physics, and Geometry" (has a Physics notation but the firsts chapters are really a good an enjoyable introduction)

***Brian Hall, Lie Groups, Lie Algebras (to get closer to something Mathematical)

***Kirillov," Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras "

From this one on you can start reading whatever text you prefer and you should have the instruments to understand what are they talking about. Classic references are Procesi and Knapp

Comment: I haven't studied Differential Geometry or Riemannian Geometry. Thank you very much for the references, I really needed a path.

Comment: But you're final aim what is exactly? I mean do you have a specific purpose or area of mathematics which you're interested in or it's just for mathematical knowledge? Because it's really a wide argument that can be treated in very different ways and bibliography should vary accordingly. If you're aim are geometrical maybe at some point you'll need to study some Differential Geometry.

Comment: If everything goes well, I want to take a class called Matrix Groups next year. This is one reason. Also I want to learn topological groups & Lie theory to widen my knowledge on abstract algebra.

Comment: I then suppose you're undergraduate. Then maybe you should also have a look to John Stillwell, "Naive Lie Theory". If you can I would stick to the bibliography I've already told you, but if the books are too hard then you can take a look at that one

Comment: Yes I am, this is my last semester. I will check Stillwell too, thank you.